# Android How set Image to another imageview by Sending Image resId using function

Tags: android, image, imageview

I want to do that on click of an imageview a function will call ShowPegs(int resId), which will place that image to another imageview.
there are many different imageView, each one send its own image ID to function and function will place that image to an another image view
when i run the code its not placing that image to another imageview
any Help will be appreciated

may be its bit confusing 
here is my code

Switch code

```
case R.id.sp_pink:
        showPeg(R.id.sp_pink);
        ShowToast(context, "Color is Pink");
        break;
    case R.id.sp_golden:
        showPeg(R.id.sp_golden);
        ShowToast(context, "Color is Golden");
        break;
    case R.id.sp_seagreen:
        showPeg(R.id.sp_green);
        ShowToast(context, "Color is SeaGreen");
        break;

    }
```

showPeg(int resId) Function Code 
one_first, one_two, one_three, one_four are other image view where i want to place the image

```
public void showPeg(int resId) {
    if(iRow==1){
        if(iPlace==1){
            one_first.setImageResource(resId);
            iPlace++;
        }
        if(iPlace ==2){
            one_two.setImageResource(resId);
            iPlace++;
        }
        if(iPlace==3){
            one_three.setImageResource(resId);
            iPlace++;
        }
        if(iPlace==4){
            one_four.setImageResource(resId);
            iPlace=0;
            iRow++;
        }

    }
}
```

Thank in Advance :)

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly? Is it placing some images or only image is placed or what?

Comment: Have you debugged in `showPeg()` to see what lines are hit? Also, you shouldn't need the switch. You should just be able to do `showPeg(v.getId())` or whatever depending on how your `onClick()` is setup

Comment: @siris_cac i am unable to set image resource to my other imageview

Comment: @codeMagic I'll try it and let you know if it works

Comment: @codeMagic I tried it but i got exception of Resource Not found

Comment: Did you put breakpoints or logs in that method as I suggested to see what is/isn't called? It's hard to say without more information.

Comment: @codeMagic Yes I tried Logs
first condition get execute and exception occurred and it run all other remaining conditions as well